# libyaml: retrieve the key of the root element

Tags: qt, yaml, qt6, libyaml

Given this simple YAML example:

```
{CR: {ab: 12}}
```

I want to retrieve `CR`. Perhaps I don't know the correct word to identify the "root key", hence I didn't find anything useful.
I use [QtYaml](https://gist.github.com/brcha/d392b2fe5f1e427cc8a6) that is based upon [libyaml](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml), in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
QString yaml = "{CR: {ab: 12}}";
YAML::Node root = YAML::Load(yaml.toStdString().c_str());

QString key;
YAML::convert<QString>().decode(root, key);
qDebug() << key;
```

It returns an empty string.
What I have to do in order to have `key = "CR"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not libyaml; libyaml doesn't have a C++ interface with namespaces. Judging by the look of the API calls, you're using [yaml-cpp](/questions/tagged/yaml-cpp).

YAML documents have a root node, in your case this is a *mapping*. A mapping is a collection node and thus doesn't properly convert into a string. What you want is to extract the fist key of that mapping:

```cpp
root.begin()->first.as<QString>();
```

`begin()` returns an iterator over the root mappings key-value pairs. `->` dereferences to its first item. `first` retrieves the key. `as<QString>()` converts the key to `QString` and returns it.